# Swift Navigation bar not appearing when storyboard is referenced after login

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistoryboard

When I launch a build for the application the login and signup work just fine but when it transfers to the HomeVC storyboard it appears empty. To make sure that it is referenced correctly I put labels on it and those were appearing during builds what just really remains invisible is the navigation bar. Pls help :)

How the HomeVC storyboard is referenced in Login and Signup

Login:

```
 else {
      let homeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController) as? HomeViewController
       self.view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
       self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

SignUp:

```
func transitionToHome(){
     let homeViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController) as? HomeViewController
     view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
     view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Here is the login storyboard
[image: Here is the login storyboard]

The navigation bar is clearly apparent in the storyboards
[image: The navigation bar is clearly apparent in the storyboards]

Comment: What is the name of storyboard that has the HomeViewController? Are you using same storyboard for all the views?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a segue

```
// This is used to perform the segue with the approporiate identifier
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Your unique identifer of the seugue", sender: self)

// Prepare for segue is used if you want to modify some properities in the desintation viewcontroller
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Your identifier of the segue" {
        // This is used to fetch the destination and cast it to pass over the values
        if let dc = segue.destination as? YourClassOfTheDestination {
            // Here can you type into dc and pass over the values

            //Example
            dc.curentFruit = "Pear"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an image on how to specify the custom identifier of the segue in the storyboard. [Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNA09.png)

If you don't want the navigation bar to be visible in certain screens you can simply use:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
}
```

Remember to make it visible again when the view disappears.

Great question, hope the answer helps!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is you are making the view controller the key window and you are not adding the navigation controller. Try making the home view controller's navigation controller the key window.